# Saving Custom Document Properties in a Loop

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to save the values of data that have been input into my form. There are a total of about 50 different fields to save across 5 different agents, so I loaded the data into arrays.

I've tried saving the fields in a loop, but it doesn't seem to work in a loop, only if each field has a separate line, which is a lot of code and messy. The Ag1Name, Ag2Name and Ag3Name are the names of my textboxes that the user enters to populate the form.

```
    Sub LoadAndSaveData()
    NumberofAgents = 3
    Dim AgentName(3) as String
    AgentName(1) = Ag1Name.Value
    AgentName(2) = Ag2Name.Value
    AgentName(3) = Ag3Name.Value


    For Count = 1 To NumberOfAgents
          With ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
              .Add Name:="AgentName" & Count, LinkToContent:=False, Value:=AgentName(Count), Type:=msoPropertyTypeString
          End With
      Next Count

    End Sub
```

The data doesn't get saved to the Custom Document Properties when the code is set up in a loop like the above. Since there are so many values to save and all the data is already in arrays, I would much prefer to use a loop rather than write out a separate line of code for all ~50 of the values. It does seem to work when each field is saved in a separate line of code.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to add a working sample of the non-loop code that does what you expect? I suspect there is more difference between the two than just the loop.

Comment: Also, 0..2 instead of 1..3

Comment: FWIW the code you post does run for me: it successfully creates the properties and populates them. The only problem I had was that there are no `Dim` statements for `NumberOfAgents` and `Count` - which tells me you don't have `Option Explicit` at the top of the code module. I very much recommend you use `Option Explicit` as it can save having to trouble-shoot problems arising from spelling errors and it will provide Intellisense for writing out variable names.

Comment: Also, as cxw intimates, arrays in VBA are 0-based. The first member is array(0), not 1. Logically, then, setting the number of array elements is *n*-1. Your code works because you're setting the total number of elements to 3 and are assigning three values. But there are actually four array elements in this example - VBA creates `AgentName(0)` as well, in memory. This is just for your information / understanding and has nothing to do with whatever is happening...

Comment: I guess I need to get better at posting on SO. My apologies. I do have a Dim statement for Count and NumberofAgents, Option Explicit and Option Base 1 in my code, I just didn't think to include that in the code that I posted. I would edit it, but Cindy Meister told me before that editing a question after it has been answered is against SO forum rules. Here is a line of code that is not in a loop that does work:
ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="AgentName1", LinkToContent:=False, Value:=AgentName(1), Type:=msoPropertyTypeString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a little stupid... I just realized that the reason that the code wasn't working was that the variable NumberofAgents was not being calculated correctly elsewhere in my code. I've got it working now. Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would probably get what you want. You don't really need to count the document properties first, only increment with the ones you want to update. Hopefully the only document properties you want contain the name `AgentName` in it.

```
ReDim AgentName(0) As String
Dim P As Long


For Each c In ThisDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
    If InStr(1, c.Name, "AgentName", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve AgentName(P)
        AgentName(P) = c.Value
        P = P + 1
    End If
Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

As a guest I cannot post a comment here, but the code you gave works OK here.

However, there is a problem with creating legacy custom document properties programmatically, because doing that does not mark the document as "changed". When you close the document, Word does not necessarily save it and you lose the Properties and their values.

However, if you actually open up the Custom Document Property dialog, Word does then mark the document as "changed" and the Properties are saved.

So it is possible that the difference between your two scenarios is not the code, but that in one scenario you  have actually opened the dialog box to check the values before closing the document and in the other you have not.

If that is the case, here, I was able to change this behaviour by adding the line

```
ActiveDocument.Saved = False
```

after setting the property values.

If you do not actually need the values to be Document Properties, it might be better either to use Document Variables, which are slightly easier to use since you can add them and modify them with exactly the same code, or perhaps by storing them in A Custom XML Part, which is harder work but can be useful if you need to extract the values somewhere where Word is not available.

Comment: Thank you. I added the 
ActiveDocument.Saved = False 
line of code. I can't use the Document Variables because there is data that I need to save that are not strings, like Boolean. Also, I don't have any experience in XML and Cindy Meister said there would be a steep learning curve, so I don't want to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this even easier by looping the controls on the UserForm, testing whether the control name contains "Ag" and, if it does, create the Custom Document Property with the control's value - all in one step.

For example, the following code sample loops the controls in the UserForm. It tests whether the controls `Name` starts with "Ag". If it does, the CustomDocumentProperty is added with that control's value.

```
Sub LoadAndSaveData()
    Dim ctl As MSForms.control
    Dim controlName As String

    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        controlName = ctl.Name
        If Left(controlName, 2) = "Ag" Then
            With ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties
              .Add Name:=controlName, LinkToContent:=False, value:=ctl.value, Type:=msoPropertyTypeString
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```